# making tables with table-tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers

Why can't you add tables what the HTML `table`-tag in a question or answer on SE? For example:

> ```
> <table>
>     <td>
>         <tr>1</tr>
>         <tr>2</tr>
>         <tr>3>/tr>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         <tr>4</tr>
>         <tr>5</tr>
>         <tr>6</tr>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         <tr>7</tr>
>         <tr>8</tr>
>         <tr>9>/tr>
>     </td>
> </table>
> ```

Which result into this:

> 123
>   456
>   789

It will be easier to makeup and read your questions / answers. For now you must make your tables like this:

> ```
> -------------
> | 1 | 2 | 3 |
> ----+---+----
> | 4 | 5 | 6 |
> ----+---+----
> | 7 | 8 | 9 |
> -------------
> ```

For users who think this is an duplicate, well it isn't! I ask **WHY you can NOT** use `table`-tags, **NOT** how you can do it without it!

Comment: @JoeW: it is not a duplicate because I ask **why you can't** do it with `table`-tags and **not how** you can make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Markdown implementation used on SE, like most others, doesn't accept `<table>` et al. Some implementations have a Markdown notation for authoring tables, but not SE's.