# Why can't snippets be used in documentation and tables in questions?

Tags: discussion, documentation, markdown, stack-snippets, markdown-rendering

I find it a bit strange that snippets can't be used in documentation. I'll change [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript#t=201612231041496267955) about using `console.log()` and add a snippet with markdown code below. [Here you can find my changes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/117281?filter-tags=javascript).

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    console.log("Hello, World!");

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Also in the Q&A part of SO the markdown code doesn't render tables but in documentation it does. A thime ago I've asked this question [making tables with table-tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306690/making-tables-with-table-tags).

**My question is now:** Why can't snippets be used in documentation and tables in questions?